# Cartesian product of two ranges in SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(cri-range, criteria, sum range))?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to lookup up some values in master sheet and sum its corresponding column. The lookup value is kind of complex key made by concatenation of few columns.

I have used the following formula to sum the values.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$4:$A$1000,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10 & Sheet3!$A$1:$A$10,$E$4:$E$1000))
```

I want the above criteria to give one hundred combinations of key (i.e. Cartesian product of the keys eg. `sheet2!A1*Sheet3!A1`, `sheet2!A1*Sheet3!A2`, `sheet2!A1*Sheet3!A3`, `sheet2!A1*Sheet3!A4` .... `sheet2!A10*Sheet3!A1`,  `sheet2!A10*Sheet3!A2` ... `sheet2!A10*Sheet3!A10`)

But it's giving only ten combinations, which is one to one multiplication (i.e. `sheet2!A1*Sheet3!A1`, `sheet2!A2*Sheet3!A2`, `sheet2!A3*Sheet3!A3` ...  `sheet2!A10*Sheet3!A10` etc).

Is there any way to realize or make such criteria using the values in two columns?

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

=SUM(SUMIF($A$4:$A$1000, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10 & TRANSPOSE(Sheet3!$A$1:$A$10), $E$4:$E$1000))

Confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter